# Query to retrieve all user except those returned from another query

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data

I have to write a query through Spring data to mySql database.
I have a table User and a table Fleet with a many to many relationship, so I have another table with id_username and id_fleet.
Now I would like to know all user that I may add to a fleet, so I need all user except those that already have the specified fleet.
I tried with a sample query in Mysql workbench like this:

```
SELECT username FROM dart.user where enabled=true NOT IN (Select id_username from dart.fleet_Has_User where dart.fleet_Has_User.id_fleet= '8' )
```

but it doesn't remove user of second query. Could you help me ? Thanks

Comment: `where id_username NOT IN`

Comment: thanks, what a stupid error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use NOT IN like

```
SELECT username FROM dart.user 
where enabled=true 
and id_username NOT IN (Select id_username from dart.fleet_Has_User where dart.fleet_Has_User.id_fleet= '8' )
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    yourIdusername col of dart.user table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use left join.

```
SELECT username 
FROM dart.user u 
left join dart.fleet_Has_User fu
 on fu.user_id = u.user_id and
    fu.id_fleet= '8'
where U.enabled=true 
and fu.user_id is null
```